# node.js: how to return a value of a callback function?

Tags: node.js, callback

I have the following code (that doesn't work as expected):

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/interviews';

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var result = get_document(res);
    res.send( result // show the results of get document in the browser //)
    console.log("end");
});

app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

function get_document() {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var col = db.collection('myinterviews');
    var data = col.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
      db.close();
      return docs[0].name.toString(); // returns to the function that calls the callback
    });
  });
}
```

The function 'get_document' is supposed to return the documents stored in 'myinterviews' collection. The problem is that the line 'return docs[0]...' returns to col.find (which is the function that called the callback) and not to variable 'result' inside app.get(...).

Do you know how to make the documents return to 'result' variable?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the promise api.

the "get_document" function should return a new promise, with resolve and reject function callbacks (success/failure).

So, it should look a bit like this:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/interviews';

app.get('/', function(req, res){
var result = get_document(res).then(function (doc) {
  res.send( doc);
});
 // show the results of get document in the browser //)
console.log("end");
});

app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

function get_document() {

  return new Promise(

     function (resolve, reject)
       MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
       var col = db.collection('myinterviews');
       var data = col.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
        db.close();
        resolve(docs[0].name.toString()); // returns to the function that calls the callback
    });
  });
  );
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. As for promises - don't you think that bluebird.promisify (bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) is better?

Comment: Yeap, it could be. I haven't used it however, so I cannot comment based on experience :) .  Check this out: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278778/why-are-native-es6-promises-slower-and-more-memory-intensive-than-bluebird

Answer (score 1):

Your `get_document` function runs asynchronously. The call to `MongoClient.connect()` could take some time, so it can't return immediately. To return the value you're after from your database call, you'll have to pass a callback into the `get_document` function. So it should look something like this:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/interviews';

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var result = get_document(function(result) {
        res.send(result);
        console.log("end");
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

function get_document(done) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var col = db.collection('myinterviews');
    var data = col.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
      db.close();
      done(docs[0].name.toString()); // returns to the function that calls the callback
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise <-- you can read up on them here

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. As for promises - don't you think that bluebird.promisify (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) is better?

Comment: Admittedly, I haven't used bluebird.promisify as `Promise` has always been able to get me over the line. I will have a read over the docs and let you know what I think :)