# Bluebird.Promisify - How to create a chain of promises correct?

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

This question follows this question: [node.js: how to return a value of a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608598/node-js-how-to-return-a-value-of-a-callback-function)

I decided to write the code in the previous question by using Bluebird.promisify. This is what I wrote:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db = require('./db.js')
var Promise = require('bluebird');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var result = Promise.promisify(db.get_document);
    result().then(function(doc) {
        res.send(doc);
        console.log("end");
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

function get_document () {
  var connect = Promise.promisify(MongoClient.connect);
  connect(url).then(function(err,db) {
    var col = db.collection('myinterviews');  // !!! ERROR!!! 'db' undefined
    return col.find().toArray
  }).then(function (err, docs) {
     db.close();
     return docs[0].name;
  });
};
```

The line:

> var col = db.collection('myinterviews');

gives the error message:

> "Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of
>   undefined."

Function MongoClient.connect accepts a callback function with two arguments, so why is 'db' undefined?

Comment: I dont see MongoClient defined anywhere, this could be the issue. where is url defined.

Comment: I missed it when I copied the code. I edited the original post.

Comment: Where are you even calling  `get_document`?

Answer (score 0):

Promise does not pass err and result to same method. You have to add `catch` to get err.

Also the method you promisify takes a callback and call it with first parameter as error and other as result.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Promise = require('bluebird');

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    var result = Promise.promisify(get_document);
    result().then(function(doc) {
        res.send(doc);
        console.log("end");
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send(err.toString());
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

function get_document (callback) {
    return Promise.promisify(MongoClient.connect)(YOUR_URL)
    .then(function(db){
        return db.collection(YOUR_COLLECTION).find().toArray();
    })
    .then(function (docs) {
        return callback(null, docs[0].name);
    }).catch(function(err){
        return callback(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: Now, I get an error for "db.close()" saying: "db is not defined"

Comment: That is because db is not present in second function. That 's js 101.

Comment: OK. so also when I delete the line "db.close", docs[0].name is not transferred to res.send(doc).

Comment: You should not close connection. Create connection for your app,not for request. MongoClient will take care of connection.

Comment: It still doesn't help me. I want to know how to pass the document's content to res.send(doc)

Comment: @CrazySynthax I have updated my answer according to your requirement. check it out.